# Export datagridview rows and columns to excel with formatting

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, datagridview

I've just finished making my database databounddatagridview meet my demands, and I'd like to export it to excel. However, I'd like to only export the visible rows and columns, as well as keep the formatting. I've also overridden the paint method to "merge" some columns and/or rows. Does anyone have any idea on where to start ?

I've also overridden the paint method to "merge" some columns and/or rows. Does anyone have any idea on where to start ?

**EDIT :**
I've managed so far to come up with this, which is code taken from another source I don't remember :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileName;

            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "xls files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.Title = "To Excel";
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "Contrôle journalier du " + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + " de " + comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
                var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(this.Text);
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView2.Columns[i].Visible == true)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cell(11, i + 1).Value = dataGridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                    }
                }


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if ((dataGridView2.Rows[i].Visible == true) && (dataGridView2.Columns[j].Visible == true))
                        {
                            worksheet.Cell(i + 14, j + 1).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();
                        }
                        if (worksheet.Cell(i + 14, j + 1).Value.ToString().Length > 0)
                        {
                            XLAlignmentHorizontalValues align;

                            switch (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Alignment)
                            {
                                case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                                    break;
                                case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                                    break;
                                case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                                    break;

                                case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                                    break;
                                case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                                    break;
                                case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
                                    break;
                            }

                            
                        }
                    }
                }

                worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
                workbook.SaveAs(fileName);
            }
        }
```

Next, I'm going to figure out how to remove all blank rows, which I think isn't that hard.

**EDIT 2:**

I added a few lines after the workbook.SaveAs(fileName) line:

```
Aspose.Cells.Workbook wb = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook(fileName);

                // Get the worksheets collection in the spreadsheet.
WorksheetCollection sheets = wb.Worksheets;

                // Get first Worksheet from WorksheetCollection by index.
Aspose.Cells.Worksheet sheet = sheets[0];
                // Or by name.
                // Worksheet sheet = sheets["Sheet1"];

                // Delete the Blank Rows from the worksheet.
sheet.Cells.DeleteBlankRows();

                // Save the excel file.
wb.Save(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip rows you need another variable for the row value.  Something like code below

```
int row = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
     for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
         if ((dataGridView2.Rows[i].Visible == true) && (dataGridView2.Columns[j].Visible == true))
         {
             worksheet.Cell(row + 14, j + 1).Value = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value?.ToString();

             if (worksheet.Cell(row + 14, j + 1).Value.ToString().Length > 0)
             {
                 XLAlignmentHorizontalValues align;

                 switch (dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.Alignment)
                 {
                     case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                           align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                           break;
                     case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                       align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                       break;
                     case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopRight:
                       align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
                       break;

                     case DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                       align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                       break;
                     case DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                       align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                       break;
                     case DataGridViewContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                       align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
                       break;

                     default:
                       align = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Left;
                       break;
             }

             row++;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, I think something's wrong with it, the output is delayed. I also used the Aspose Cells library to remove blank rows

Comment: I used your code.  Wasn't sure why you were skipping 14 rows.  You can remove the plus 14.  Are the blank rows the rows that are not VISIBILE?  You do not need to remove the blank rows with Aspose.  You can do it with your existing code.

Comment: With my code, whenever a datagridviewrow is not visible, the respective excel row is empty but not removed. That's why I use Aspose afterwards.

Comment: My code using the row variable should not require the Aspose.  I think the delay is just the plus 14 in the code.